# How to Auto Invite all users of selected Group using Django admin inlines form?

Tags: django, forms, django-admin, admin, inlines

I am working on an application where currently, I have  
1) **Staff** Model is connected to User model via OneToOne Relationship and can have more than one **Group**.
2) **Meeting** model can also assigned to many **Group**. 
3) **RSVPinline** is a part with **MeetingAdmin** as a inline form.

Here i was trying to automatically ADD all '*Staff*' associated in Selected Groups in django admin form while creating Meetings.

I have tried *save_model* to add current user in meeting's '*creator*' field.

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Staff(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length = 250,verbose_name = "First Name")
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=False,verbose_name = "Meeting Group")  # protect error left to add
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True,verbose_name = "Associated as User")  # protect error left to add
    left_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True,verbose_name = "Resigned Date")

class Meeting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), blank=True, max_length=200)
    start = models.DateTimeField(_('Start'))
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=False,verbose_name = "Meeting Group")  # protect error left to add
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=False,verbose_name = "Location",on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # protect error left to add

class RSVP(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    responder =  models.ForeignKey(User, editable=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name = "Attendees", related_name='guest')
    response = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices= MEETING_RSVP, default='No response', verbose_name = "Status",null=True, blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class RSVPInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RSVP
    extra = 0


class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MeetingForm
    list_display = ('title', 'location', 'start','creator' )
    inlines = [RSVPInline, TaskInline]

    #Currently using save_model to automatically add current user as a creator
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.creator = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

My pseudo code is:

```
grouplist = Get group's list from submitted MeetingForm
stafflist = Staff.objects.filter(department__in =grouplist).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct()
Add to RSVPInline:
    values = list(for staff in stafflist:
              'responder' = staff
              'meeting' = 'meeting from  MeetingForm' 
              'response' = has a default value in model

    bulk_create() RSVPInline with values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend [save_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) *ModelAdmin* method to **perform additional actions after form object (*Meeting*) and its Inlines (*RSVPs*, if present in submitted form) are saved**:

```
class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        # call original method - saves Meeting and inlines
        super(MeetingAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        # get this form Meeting
        obj = form.instance
        # get Staff members of this meeting groups
        # and we can exclude ones already having
        # RSVP for this meeting
        stafflist = Staff.objects.filter(
            group__in=obj.group.all()
        ).exclude(
            user__guest__meeting=obj
        )
        rsvps = list(
            RSVP(responder=staff.user, meeting=obj)
            for staff in stafflist
        )
        # calls bulk_create() under the hood
        obj.rsvp_set.add(*rsvps, bulk=False)
```

** Few possibly useful notes:

- `group` field may be better to be called `groups` as it represents ManyToMany relation and returns multiple objects
- `related_name` represents [relation from the related object back to this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) so it may be more logical to use something like `invites` instead of `guest`

Comment: Thank you for your effort. i applied it to my code and it is throwing error: 'super' object has no attribute 'save_related'

Comment: Edited, forgot `self` in `super(MeetingAdmin, self)` call, or it can just be `super()` in python 3

Comment: Still throwing an error of : 
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable 

Is this because group is a many-to-many field ?

Comment: `group__in=obj.group.all()` - to fetch groups

Comment: one thing i noticed on this code is Staff Model doesn't have a field called 'meeting'
.exclude(guest__meeting=obj)

so i am getting an error .. and when i changed it to distinct() to get unique staff i got following error :
'RSVP' instance expected, got <generator object MeetingAdmin.save_related.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x04A2E878>

any clue ?

Comment: Sorry for fast answer without extensive check - thought RSVP had key to `Staff`, but it has key to `User`. Its `related_name` is `guest`, so we are accessing user's rsvp via `guest` - in staff `filter / exclude` it should then be `user__guest__meeting`. Also, Staff already has unique users (OneToOne key), so they are distinct and no need to call `distinct()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207693/discussion-between-sark-and-oleg-russkin).